# Asymptotic Expansions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Can someone explain this to me, please

(a) $\sin (1/\varepsilon) = O(1)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$,
but it is not true that $1 = O(\sin (1/\varepsilon))$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ because $\sin (1/\varepsilon)$ vanishes in
every neighborhood of $\varepsilon = 0$;

(b) What is the order of $\varepsilon \cos(1/\varepsilon)$? I think  the answer is $\varepsilon$.

Thanks

Comment: because cos(1/epsilon) = O(1) and epsilon =O(epsilon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) If it was true, then with
$$
\varepsilon _n  = \frac{1}{{\pi n}} \to 0
$$
there would be a $K>0$ such that
$$
1 \le K\sin (1/\varepsilon _n ) = K \cdot 0 = 0
$$
(contradiction).

(b) You are right since $\left| {\varepsilon \cos (1/\varepsilon )} \right| \le \left| {\varepsilon  \cdot 1} \right| = \left| \varepsilon  \right|$.

Comment: It means that there is a zero of $\sin(1/\varepsilon)$ arbitrarily close to $0$ (the zeroes are precisely the $\varepsilon_n$'s I gave in the answer).

Comment: thanks, is it the same case for cos(1/epsilon)

Comment: @FedaK Yes, you are right.

Comment: I assume you wanted to say $$\frac{d}{{d\varepsilon }}(\varepsilon \cos (1/\varepsilon )) = \cos (1/\varepsilon ) + (1/\varepsilon )\sin (1/\varepsilon ) = O(1/\varepsilon ) \ne O(1) = O\left( {\frac{d}{{d\varepsilon }}\varepsilon } \right).$$ Yes, in general $f=O(g)$ does not imply $f'=O(g')$.

Comment: If $0<\varepsilon<1$ then
$$\left| {\cos (1/\varepsilon ) + (1/\varepsilon )\sin (1/\varepsilon )} \right| \le \left| {\cos (1/\varepsilon )} \right| + \left| {(1/\varepsilon )\sin (1/\varepsilon )} \right| \le 1 + \left| {(1/\varepsilon ) \cdot 1} \right| = 1 + 1/\varepsilon  \le 1/\varepsilon  + 1/\varepsilon  \le 2/\varepsilon  = O(1/\varepsilon ).$$

Answer (score 1):

a) It does not necessarily hold that

$$f=O(g)\iff g=O(f),$$ on the opposite. In a way, you can view $f=O(g)$ as "$f\le g$", and this is not a symmetrical relation.

b) $f=O(h)$ and $g=O(j)$ implies $f\cdot g=O(h\cdot j)$.

Comment: because sin(1/ε) vanishes in every neighborhood of ε=0; that what is written in the book , what does this mean